# Three-way interaction cox hazard. (Testing the difference in impact of a two-way interaction for two groups)

Tags: r, survival, modeling, interpretation, cox-model

Some background: For my dissertation I'm working on a survival analysis on the hazard of exiting a firm for men vs women. After doing the basic analysis I want to investigate if the control variables in my model have different effects on hazard for men and women (e.g. age has more impact on men).
To do this I made a full interaction model by interacting all of my control variables with the gender variable using R.

```
Coxinteractfull <- coxph(Surv(Duration,Censoring) ~ Control1 + Control2 + ... + Control1*Gender + Control2*Gender + ...)
```

Then I checked if each of the interaction terms were significant by making a restricted model without the interaction term for each resprective control variable and comparing this with the full interaction model.

```
RestrictedControl1 <- coxph(Surv(Duration,Censoring) ~ Control1 + Control2 + ... + Control2*Gender + ...)  
anova(RestrictedControl1, Coxinteractfull)
```

I am planning on reporting this in a table, with the coefficients/hazard ratios seperately for men and women. Is this the correct way to go about this?

The current issue: I want to check if an interaction term is different for men and women, which essentially means doing a three-way interaction. The interaction is a continuous x nominal interaction. I'm not sure 1. how to model/code this and 2. how to interpret the results.

Any way of coding will lead to something like this:

| variable | coef | exp(coef) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Male:Group1:Continuous | -0.401 | 0.667 * |
| Male:Group2:Continuous | -0.600 | 0.549 |
| Female:Group1:Continuous | 0.053 | 1.055 |
| Female:Group2:Continuous | -3.449 | 0.032 |

So based on this, I would say the continuous variable only has significant impact on the hazard for men in Group 1, correct?
How do I now check if this interaction is significantly different for men and women?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really different from the issue in any regression model with interaction terms. The only difference is whether baseline predictor values are included in the baseline hazard (Cox) or contribute to an intercept term (other regression models). When you write in R with its default treatment coding of predictors:

```
outcome ~ Control * Gender
```

where `Control` is continuous, you get a set of 3 coefficients: a slope coefficient for `Control` at the baseline value of `Gender` (assuming a linear association of `Control` with log-hazard in a Cox model), a coefficient for the `Gender` difference at a value of `Control = 0`, and an interaction coefficient that can be thought of as the difference between the `Gender` values in the slope coefficient for `Control`.*

If you have an additional 2-level predictor `Group` then you can simply include that in your model:

```
outcome ~ Control * Gender * Group
```

and examine the significance of the single reported 3-way interaction term. That will tell you directly whether the `Control:Group` interaction term  differs as a function of `Gender`.

If you have a large enough data set you can include 3-way interactions for all of your `Continuous` control variables:

```
outcome ~ Continuous1 * Gender * Group + Continuous2 * Gender * Group + ...
```

The `Gender` coefficient then represents the `Gender`-associated difference in the baseline `Group` with all `Continuous` variables at 0. With 2 levels of `Group`, its coefficient represents the corresponding difference for cases in the baseline `Gender` with all `Continuous` variables at 0.

Each `Continuous:Gender` interaction coefficient is as for `Control:Gender` in the first model, but only for cases in the baseline `Group`. Each `Control:Group` interaction coefficient is the `Group` difference in the `Control` coefficient at the baseline `Gender`. The significance of each 3-way interaction coefficient will answer your question about `Group:Control` interaction differences between the `Genders`.

Be careful, as the table of coefficients that you show wouldn't typically be reported that way by default. If `Male` and `Group1` are the reference categories, then those categories won't show up in the default output. There would be no `Male:Group1:Continuous` interaction term; the coefficient for `Continuous` will represent the `Continuous` effect at that set of reference values.

What you show as `Male:Group2:Continuous` would be reported as the `Group2:Continuous` interaction term. `Female:Group1:Continuous` would be the `Female:Continuous` interaction term. The only 3-way interaction reported would be `Female:Group2:Continuous`. Remember that under usual treatment coding each of those interactions represents *differences* from lower levels in the interaction hierarchy.

You can use those coefficient estimates and their covariances to construct survival curves for any particular combination of predictor values. It's very easy to make mistakes in putting all that information together. With interactions in survival models I use the `survplot()`, `Predict()`, and `contrast()` functions in the R [`rms` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=rms).

---

*It's not clear that you have to do all of the restricted-model comparisons that you propose, as the significance of the `Control:Gender` interaction terms should be reported directly from the full model.

Comment: Thank you for this extensive reply, it's very helpfull. I have a more indepth question about the reporting of the tables that you talked about: I saw some papers showing a table where they show the HR of variables separately for two groups (in my case this would be men and women). As per your comment, I'm unsure if this is a fiable way to do this AND if so, how I should interpret the output. For example with the first coding I put down I would get something like:
Variable 1 :                  Coef  -0.125, exp(Coef) 0.883 *
Female*Variable1:       Coef  0.420, exp(Coef) 1.522 *

Comment: So if I would want to see if the HR of variable 1 is different for men and women, could I do that based on these results? If so how?

Comment: @KHT the details depend on the complexity of your model. For a simple model with a `Gender:variable1` interaction term but no higher-order interactions like `Gender:variable1:Group`, the coefficient for the `Gender:variable1` interaction gives you the _extra_ log-hazard for females versus males with respect to `variable1`. The corresponding p-value indicates the significance. With higher-order interactions, you have to think carefully about just what you mean by "if the HR of variable 1 is different for men and women," as that difference might depend on the `Group` membership.

Comment: Right, so if I wanted to see if the variables have different effects on the probability of exit rates for men compared to women (e.g. aging raises the probability of exit for men but not for women), would I then be able to say (with the outcomes I just described) that for men the effect of variable 1 (e.g. age) is  Coef -0.125, exp(Coef) 0.883, while for women it's Coef (-0.125+0.420), exp(Coef) 0.883*1.522. Or is this incorrect?

Comment: @KHT that seems to be correct for the point estimates, but you also need to calculate the standard errors around the point estimates to say if this is "significantly" different between men and women. That requires the variance-covariance matrix of the coefficient estimates. I'd recommend using something like the `contrast()` function in the `rms` package, linked in the answer, to avoid errors in the calculations and to make sure that you have specified other important variables adequately, particularly if you have higher-order interactions.

Comment: @KHT an explicit warning that's implicit above: if you have higher-order interaction terms like `Gender:variable1:Group` then the coefficients that you use above for `variable1` and the `Gender:variable1` interaction only hold for the reference level of `Group` (under the usual treatment coding of predictors). In that case, such a calculation shouldn't be taken as an overall measure of the male/female difference in the effect of `variable1`, just as the difference within that reference group.

Comment: Side note: The sample size needed to support interaction analysis can be amazingly high.  Basically, the number of subjects in the least frequent three-way group (binning age into say 4 intervals temporarily) needs to be in the neighborhood of 100.  Other wise any non-astounding interaction effect (e.g., overall $P$-value for 3-way terms = 0.6) gives you no information because of power issues.